# When did Captain America and Peggy Carter dance in the comics?

Tags: marvel, comics, captain-america, episode-identification

Sometime this year, I read a comic book or graphic novel in which Steve Rogers (Captain America) returned from the ice, and gets to dance at last with an old Peggy Carter.

Does anyone know which comic that was? I can't find it anymore.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sometime this year? That can't have been that long ago.